# Nagios4 prompts for username/password but has limited capabilities after logged in

Tags: networking, nagios

I followed the instructions from here:
https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=56970
And now nagios prompts me to log in.
It is correctly parsing the username/password.

Unfortunately, I still cannot access some functions and I get this error:

**It appears as though you do not have permission to view information for any of the hosts you requested...**

Here is my apache2.conf file:

```
listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/nagios4 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4
ScriptAlias /nagios4/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4
Alias /nagios4/stylesheets /etc/nagios4/stylesheets
Alias /nagios4 /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs

<Directory /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs>
    Options     +ExecCGI
    #  SSLRequireSSL
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    <RequireAll>
         Require all granted
         AuthName "Nagios Access"
         AuthType Basic
         AuthUserFile /etc/nagios4/htdigest.users
         Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch (/usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4|/etc/nagios4/stylesheets)>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require ip  ::1/128 fc00::/7 fe80::/10 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 169.254.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 10.13.0.0/16
    <Files "cmd.cgi">
    AuthDigestDomain "Nagios4"
    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile    "/etc/nagios4/htdigest.users"
    AuthGroupFile   "/etc/group"
    AuthName    "Nagios4"
    #AuthType   Digest
    AuthType    Basic
    #Require all    granted
    Require valid-user
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>

#<Directory /usr/share/nagios4/htdocs>
#    Options    +ExecCGI
#</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to access it from another host.  My IP range is 10.13.0.0.
I would appreciate any suggestions anyone may have!

Comment: I have tried disabling authentication in the apache configuration file, but I still have problems issuing commands via the web page.  I still get the "It appears as though you do not have permission to view information for any of the hosts you requested..." error

Comment: If I could completely disable user authorization, that would fine also.  This is on a home server (behind a firewall) with limited access.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working for me. Could vary I suppose depending on other steps taken.
Before this step and right after installation I just did

> sudo htdigest -c /etc/nagios4/htdigest.users Nagios4 nagiosadmin

Then I commented a few more lines than you did

> ```
> #Require ip ::1/128 fc00::/7 fe80::/10 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 169.254.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
> #<Files "cmd.cgi">
>     AuthDigestDomain "Nagios4"
>     AuthDigestProvider file
>     AuthUserFile    "/etc/nagios4/htdigest.users"
>     AuthGroupFile   "/etc/group"
>     AuthName        "Nagios4"
>     AuthType        Digest
>     #Require all    granted
>     Require valid-user
> #</Files>
> ```

And in the next step I set

> use_authentication=1

in

> /etc/nagios4/cgi.cfg